# Dynamically update a list used in multiple Select Inputs in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following problem related to this relatively simple code that doesn't work:

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)


server <- function(input, output) {

  list_of_stuff=c("Car","Cat","Dog","Hat","Baby","Tractor")
  reactive_stuff_list <- eventReactive({list(input$select_1,input$select_2,input$select_3)},{

    selection_1=input$select_1
    selection_2=input$select_2
    selection_3=input$select_3

    list_of_stuff=list_of_stuff[! list_of_stuff %in% selection_1]
    list_of_stuff=list_of_stuff[! list_of_stuff %in% selection_2]
    list_of_stuff=list_of_stuff[! list_of_stuff %in% selection_3]
    return(list_of_stuff)
  })

  output$select1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "select_1", label = "Select some stuff",
              choices=reactive_stuff_list(), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$select2 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "select_2", label = "Select some stuff",
                choices=reactive_stuff_list(), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })

  output$select3 <- renderUI({
    selectInput(inputId = "select_3", label = "Select some stuff",
                choices=reactive_stuff_list(), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)
  })



}
```

**ui.R**

```
ui <- mainPanel(
  uiOutput('select1'),
  uiOutput('select2'),
  uiOutput('select3')
)
```

*WHAT I WOULD LIKE IT TO DO:* 
I start with some list of elements. Then as soon as I select some elements in one of the "selectInputs" (say number 1) the initial list gets updated in the other ones as well so I can't select the ones I selected in number 1 in number 2/3.

Sadly I have no idea how to achieve this; tried some stuff but didn't get anything usable.

Basically I want them to be kind of linked so they are seperate but work together.

If I'm not clear, I can try to explain it differently.
Any guidance would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the way it's written, all of your `selectInput` elements get re-rendered every time any of their inputs change (i.e. when your `reactive_stuff_list()` changes). The re-rendering changes the selection back to `NULL`, since that's the value you set in the `selectInput` calls in your `renderUI`s.

Below is an implementation that works around that issue by retaining the current input when updating the available choices.

```r
library(shiny)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # Stuff lists

  LIST_OF_STUFF = c("Car", "Cat", "Dog", "Hat", "Baby", "Tractor")

  # Update available choices

  other_select <- function(inputId) {

    # Return a reactive list of input values from all 'select_#' input elements,
    # except for the input element given as the inputId argument.  This allows
    # updating a 'select_#' input element whenever any other 'select_#' input
    # element changes.

    reactive({
      select_ids <- grep("^select_\\d+$", names(input), value = T)
      other_select_ids <- setdiff(select_ids, inputId)

      # Single bracket indexing doesn't work for reactive lists: can't simply
      # select inputs based on character vector.  Work around by iterating with
      # double bracket indexing.

      purrr::map(other_select_ids, purrr::partial(`[[`, input))
    })

  }

  render_select <- function(i, label = "Select some stuff") {

    # A selectInput named 'select_<i>' that re-renders whenever _other_
    # selectInputs named 'select_#' change.  Removes choices that have been made
    # in the other selectInputs named 'select_#', while preserving the existing
    # selections.

    renderUI({

      # Save current input; isolated so that changing own input won't cause the
      # object to re-render.

      this_id <- paste0("select_", i)
      this_input <- isolate(input[[this_id]])

      # Update choices based on selections made in other 'select_#' elements.

      selected_elsewhere <- unlist(other_select(this_id)())
      available_choices <- setdiff(LIST_OF_STUFF, selected_elsewhere)

      selectInput(inputId = this_id, label = label, choices = available_choices, 
        selected = this_input, multiple = TRUE)
    })
  }

  output$select_1 <- render_select(1)
  output$select_2 <- render_select(2)
  output$select_3 <- render_select(3)

}

ui <- mainPanel(uiOutput("select_1"), uiOutput("select_2"), uiOutput("select_3"))

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I accept this answer since this is what worked best for me. I adapted it into my code and it does great.

Answer (score 1):

`?updateSelectInput` is your friend here... a simple example:

```
stack.shiny <- function(){
  dat_set <- mtcars

  all_cars <- row.names(dat_set)

  car_brands <- unique(stri_extract_first_words(all_cars))



  server <- function(input, output, session) {

    output$car_brands <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = 'select1', label = 'choose brand',
                  choices = car_brands)
    })

    output$cars <- renderUI({
      selectInput(inputId = 'select2', label = 'choose car',
                  choices = all_cars)
    })

    observeEvent(input$select1, {
      x <- input$select1
      find_pat <- sprintf('^%s', x)
      these_cars <- all_cars[grepl(find_pat, all_cars, perl = TRUE)]
      # Can also set the label and select items
      updateSelectInput(session, "select2",
                        choices = these_cars,
                        selected = NULL)
    })
  }

  ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('car_brands'),
    uiOutput('cars')
  )

  shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Comment: I tested your example and I'm not sure it does what I need it to do. I will play around with `updateSelectinput` some more though, thanks.

Comment: Thank you. It is good advice, using `observeEvent` with `updateSelectInput`.